# Pass Flask route parameters into a decorator

Tags: python, flask

I have written a decorator that attempts to check we have post data for a Flask POST route:

Here's my decorator:

```
def require_post_data(required_fields=None):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            for required_field in required_fields:
                if not request.form.get(required_field, None):
                    return jsonify({"error": "Missing %s from post data." %
                                    required_field}), 400
            else:
                if not request.form:
                    return jsonify({"error": "No post data, aborting."}), 400
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_function
    return decorator
```

And I have two routes, with with a URL param and the other without:

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request

mod = Blueprint('contacts', __name__, url_prefix='/contacts')


@mod.route('/', methods=['POST'])
@require_post_data(['customer_id', 'some_other_required_field'])
def create_contact():
    # Do some business


@mod.route('/<int:contact_id>', methods=['POST'])
@require_post_data
def update_contact(contact_id):
    # Do some business
```

When I run a test that hits `update_contact`, I'm getting the following exception:

```
TypeError: decorator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'contact_id'
```

But it looks like `create_contact` is working as expected.

Why is `contact_id` being passed into `decorator()`?

Comment: Old post but where have you defined the `required_fields` dictionary that you are passing to the `@require_post_data` decorator?

Comment: Typo - that should be a list: `@require_post_data(['customer_id', 'some_other_required_field'])`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you're just missing one thing, which is to actually call `require_post_data` to produce a decorator function in the `update_contact` route. This should fix it:

```
@mod.route('/<int:contact_id>', methods=['POST'])
@require_post_data() # <- note the parens
def update_contact(contact_id):
    # Do some business
```

The detailed explanation is that what you expected to happen (and what is happening in `create contact`) is that the the view function is being modified by the `decorator` *produced* by `require_post_data`. In your `update_contact` above, what is actually happening is that the view function is being passed to `require_post_data` *itself* and simply used as the value of the `required_fields` parameter. This doesn't cause an error so `require_post_data` happily returns `decorator` which is then routed to when you hit `/<int>`, causing it to be passed `contact_id` as a keyword argument, resulting in the error you saw.

Comment: No problem! This question is really interesting to me because it illustrates a few things I see as problems with python.

Comment: @Chris You can actually fix this by checking if `required_fields` is callable: `return decorator(required_fields) if callable(required_fields) else decorator` will let you call `@require_post_data` with or without parenthesis.

Comment: A little unrelated, but do you guys know if there is a way to use the variable passed into the decorator in other parts of the script? I need to use the variable that is passed into the decorator for some mysql querying. How can this be done? Thanks