# Flask pass POST parameters to custom decorator

Tags: python, flask, http-post

I've seen the posts on passing `GET` parameters and hardcoded parameters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310496/flask-decorator-cant-pass-a-parameter-from-url) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605764/pass-flask-route-parameters-into-a-decorator).

What I am trying to do is pass `POST` parameters to a custom decorator. The `route` is not actually rendering a page but rather processing some stuff and sending the results back through an AJAX call.

The decorator looks like this:

```
# app/util.py

from functools import wraps
from models import data

# custom decorator to validate symbol
def symbol_valid():
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def decorated_function(symbol, *args, **kwargs):
            if not data.validate_symbol(symbol):
                return jsonify({'status': 'fail'})
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_function
    return decorator
```

The view looks something like this:

```
# app/views/matrix_blueprint.py

from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify

from ..models import data
from ..util import symbol_valid

matrix_blueprint = Blueprint('matrix_blueprint', __name__)

# routing for the ajax call to return symbol details
@matrix_blueprint.route('/route_line', methods=['POST'])
@symbol_valid
def route_line():
    symbol = request.form['symbol'].upper()
    result = data.get_information(symbol)
    return jsonify(**result)
```

I understand that I can actually call `@symbol_valid()` when I pass a parameter through `GET` like this `/quote_line/<symbol>` but I need to `POST`.

The question then is how can my decorator access the `POST`ed variable?

Comment: `symbol` is not a url param in that post route, you would need to get the form into the decorator and check it in there I'm guessing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution. Imported Flask's `request` module into the `util.py` module which contains the decorator. Removed the outer function as well.

See code:

```
# app/util.py

from flask import request # <- added

from functools import wraps
from models import data

# custom decorator to validate symbol

def symbol_valid(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs): # <- removed symbol arg
        symbol = request.form['symbol'] # <- paramter is in the request object
        if not data.validate_symbol(symbol):
            return jsonify({'status': 'fail'})
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return symbol_valid
```

Answer (score 0):

The `decorator` accept a `func` parameter. You must use your decorator like `@symbol_valid()` or make the function `symbol_valid` accept a `func` parameter.

If you are doing it right, you can access the `request` object anywhere during the request cycle. It just works.